# Shell script to fetch mysql query data in csv file and send to mail

Tags: mysql, shell, email, scripting

Need to extract the below query data along with header in csv file using shell script.

```
SELECT CustomerID,CompanyName,FirstName,LastName,Phone,Email,CreationDate,(NoDue+FirstBktTot+SecondBktTot+ThirdBktTot+FourBktTot+FiveBktTot+SixBktTot+SevenBktTot+EightBktTot) - TotalPayment as TotOS from cust_details;
```

**Shell Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

EMAIL_IDS="test@test.com"

CSV_NAME=./Cust_`date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`.csv

mysql -u admin --password=admin db_rpt < ./RB.sql | tee $CSV_NAME

mailx -a $CSV_NAME -s "Customer details" $EMAIL_IDS
```

I am not receiving mail & script output displayed on screen.
Data inserted in CSV & file also generated but file column header appearing not properly

How hide output while script running?Please see the attached screen snap.
How to send generated csv file in mail
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz1jg.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific errors are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error but sql output appearing on screen & mailx functionality not working.

Comment: Why use `tee`? What happens if you use `mysql -u admin --password=admin db_rpt <./RB.sql >$CSV_NAME` ? Please [edit] your question to let us know?

Comment: Hi Jones, My script is working fine but while script is running that time query records are displaying on screen and terminal also not closing.

Comment: Hi Jones, Please see attached screen snap.